# How can i implement a for loop in parseJson?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm newbie at JavaScript, and i'm having some issues using parse Json.

I have one array in PHP, and i'm passing the values from the PHP to JavaScript.

The problem is that i inserted the values inside a While loop, and When i get multiple values:

> Value 1
>   Value 2

I receive this:

```
[{"id":"1","value":"1","month":"2"}, {"id":"1","value":"2","month":"2"}]
```

And to print the values i have to do that:

```
alert(obj[0].name);
alert(obj[1].name);
```

And i want to print the values together

How can i use a for loop in this situation? I just need a simple example to implement on my code, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can get the length of the array using obj.length and then iterate over them and put all the values in a single variable. and then print/alert.

```
var len= obj.length;
var str="";
for(i=0;i<=len;i++)
{
str+=obj[i].name+' ';
}
```

something in the line, tied to your requirements.

Hope it helps.